# Etymology of term "Vig", or "Vigorish"?

Tags: etymology

So I always presumed the term "vig" or "vigorish" (meaning, at least how I perceive the meaning, a bookie or loan shark's "take", or reward, for facilitating a deal of some sort) to have a Yiddish origin; maybe just because of the way the word sounds.

I came across a Russian person on another Stack Exchange site whose name was "вы́игрыш", which has a meaning akin to the English word and idea of "prize". вы́игрыш is pronounced "Viglesh". Could our slang term be derived from the Russian word for "prize"?

Comment: NM, I looked it up on Wikipedia (duh) and it says it is both: Yiddish derived from the Russian word for "prize",  вы́игрыш...

Comment: You can answer your own question, although this seems more general reference now.

Comment: When asking about etymology, basic research should include at the very least a visit to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=vigorish)

Comment: @Cascabel, there are very pronounced Slavic influences in Yiddish - the most striking are grammatical (leading some to posit a Slavic, rather than Germanic origin for the language), but there's significant lexical borrowing as well.  Ex. **grandfather**, Yiddish: *zayde*; Polish: *dziadek*; Belarussian: *dzied*; German: *Großvater* or *Opa* -  **stray**, Yiddish: *blondzhen*; Polish: *zabłąkany*; Belarussian: *zabludziŭsia*; German: *streunend*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OED: updated (OED Third Edition, December 2019).

**Vig - Vigorish:**

> **Origin:** Probably of multiple origins. A borrowing from Russian. Probably also partly a borrowing from Yiddish. Etymon: Russian vyigryš.
>
> **Etymology:** < Russian vyigryš gain, winnings (18th cent. or earlier; < vyigrat′ to gain, to win (a prefixed derivative < igra game) + -yš, suffix forming nouns), probably via an (apparently unattested) Yiddish borrowing from the Russian noun.
>
> The β. forms show remodelling of the ending after -age suffix.

Comment: If Yidish figures in the etymology of the English noun vigorish, let us see evidence for the alleged Yidish word  in question here (װיגריש*?), which to my knowledge has never been found in any Yidish text.

Comment: The OED does not say that the word "vyigryš" is Yiddish. Pleaser read "**Origin**" and "**Etymology**" again - with particular reference to "unattested".